# AppleScript performing a click while Command (or another modifier) is pressed

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I know you can perform keyboard shortcuts with AppleScript like this:

```
-- to perform Cmd + P
tell application "System Events"
   keystroke "P" using {command down}
end tell
```

Now I would like to take it a step further. I would like to perform a mouse click while a modifier is down.

I tried the following:

```
-- to perform Cmd + click
tell application "System Events"
   key down command
   tell application process "Some application" to tell button "SomeButton" to click
   key up command
end tell
```

But this doesn't yield the same result as physically performing the Cmd + click.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it may be better to script this directly, if possible.  However, if it is not possible you can always click on any point on the screen while holding down a modifier key.  For example:

```
    do shell script "cliclick kd:cmd c:28,11"
```

will click on screen coordinates (28, 11) while holding down the command key.  The screen coordinates you want to click can be manually identified with your cursor by holding down command + shift + 4. To make the above script work you will need a copy of the free Terminal/Command Line app [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/).

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier to try to think about what event you are trying to trigger instead of using the mouse to do it. Afraid I can't be of more help, but that would be my approach.

Comment: this should have been a comment not an answer